# Create HTML Draft from Google App script using GmailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, gmail, spreadsheet

I want to create a Google App Script to get Gmail Draft with a signature, by collecting data from a google spreadsheet. by default,

```js
function Loop_Email_Drafts() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var index = 2;
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

for (;index <= lastRow; index++){
var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(index, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
var ccmail = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
var subject = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
var message = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();


GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, message, {cc: ccmail});


}// End of For Loop
}// End of Function
```

google app script is creating a plain text draft from which I cant add my signature(my signature also contains an image).

Currently, I m using the below code to generate a draft but without a signature is worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use htmlBody:

If you just want to add an HTML body to the draft, you can use the following method:

- [GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String,Object))

Where `options` refers to an object that can contain a series of advanced parameters, including:

> - **htmlBody**: if set, devices capable of rendering HTML will use it instead of the required body argument; you can add an optional inlineImages field in HTML body if you have inlined images for your email
> - **inlineImages**: a JavaScript object containing a mapping from image key (`String`) to image data ([BlobSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source.html)); this assumes that the `htmlBody` parameter is used and contains references to these images in the format **<img src="cid:imageKey" />**

That is, you define the image you want in `inlineImages` and add them to your HTML using the corresponding `imageKey`. Here's an example of how this could be done:

```
const html = "<p>Whatever</p><img src=\"cid:yourImageKey\" />";
const options = {
  htmlBody: html,
  inlineImages: {
    yourImageKey: YOUR_IMAGE_BLOBSOURCE
  }
}
GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, '', options);
```

#### Update: add signature:

You can actually [manage signatures](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#managing_signatures) via Gmail API, and therefore with Apps Script (using the [Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)).

In order to add your actual signature to your draft, you can do the following:

- [Enable the Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).
- Retrieve your signature using [users.settings.sendAs.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/get).
- Add this signature to your `htmlBody`.

```
const signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs
                      .get("me", "email_address_or_alias")
                      .signature;
const html = "<div>YOUR_HTML_BODY</div><br>" + signature;
const options = {
  htmlBody: html,
  cc: ccmail
}
GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, '', options);
```

Comment: Thank you @ Iamblichus, could you please help me more.

I'm new at Google app script  / JavaScript. can you please guide me that what lines should I write on my HTML tab in the google app script to get the signature in my email draft? and is my above Google script need to be amend ?

PS: Signature is already saved in Gmail Settings.

Comment: @MehdiAbbas I have updated my answer with an explanation of how to add an actual signature to your draft, let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: your code is working fine, but I can't add CC email IDs.

GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, '', options, {cc: ccmail});

it gives error
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.createDraft. (line 79, file "Code")

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its working, 
1-how to upvote and accept?

Comment: 1 last thing if is it possible for you, that I want to add a column named "Attachment Link" and provide a path of the file which I need as an attachment. can is it possible?

Comment: @MehdiAbbas You're welcome. See [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400) and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @MehdiAbbas Regarding your last comment, that's totally unrelated to your original question, so I'd recommend you to post a new question if you're having problems with this.

Comment: upvote and accept done
please check the below link of my other question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/67016913/14418455