# Attach file from PC in Gmail Draft using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, automation, gmail, spreadsheet

Currently, I m using Google App script to create Gmail Draft from Spreadsheet, The last thing that is missing is I want to attach the file in "Gmail draft" directly from the computer instead of uploading G-Drive.

below is my current code.

here I want to add a column named "File Path" where I will enter the path of the file which I need to attach in said Email. then GS should automatically pick the file from my pc said path and attach it in Gmail Draft.

Thanks in Advance.

```js
function Loop_Email_Drafts_with_Signature() {

const signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var index = 2;
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

for (;index <= lastRow; index++){
var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(index, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
var ccmail = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
var subject = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
var message = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();

  
const html = "<div> </div><br>" + signature;
const options = {
  htmlBody: message + html,
  cc: ccmail
}  
GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, '', options);



}// End of For Loop
}// End of Function
```

PS: I'm new to Google App Script / Java script. so please help in detail by writing / amending my current code.

Comment: have you looked though https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads

Comment: Yes, but actually I'm new to programming, come here for learning purposes, the above link is difficult for me to understand as I'm on starting level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this code after many kicks :)

Sharing for others for community Benifits.

```js
function DownloadAndSendWithSignature123() {
  
  
  //DECLARATIONS
  const signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
  var sheetName = "Test email GAS";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var to = sourceSheet.getRange("B8").getValue();
  var ccmail = sourceSheet.getRange("B9").getValue();
  var body = sourceSheet.getRange("B13").getValue();
  var filename = sourceSheet.getRange("K5").getValue();
  var pdfName = filename;
  var subject = sourceSheet.getRange("B11").getValue();
  var link = sourceSheet.getRange("K3").getValue();
  
  
  //DOWNLOAD FILE
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link);
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
  //var folder = DocsList.getFolder('StackOverflow');
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID Goes here");
  
  var file =  folders.createFile(response);
   
  debugger;  // Stop to observe if in debugger
  
  
  
  
  

  //SAVE FILE TO DRIVE
  var listOfFiles = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename); //returns FileIterator of files that match name given.
  if(listOfFiles.hasNext()){ //We should check if there is a file in there and die if not.
    var file = listOfFiles.next(); //gets first file in list.
        
    // SEND EMAIL THAT FILE
    
    const html = "<div> </div><br>" + signature;
    const options = {
      htmlBody: body + html,
      cc: ccmail,
      attachments: file
      
    }  
    GmailApp.createDraft(to, subject, '', options);

  }else{
    console.log("Error no file in listOfFiles. Email not sent.");
  }
 }
```